# lsof output present deleted file names with ; and some string

Tags: linux, unix, centos, centos7, lsof

I'm trying to understand the output of my lsof command, more specifically, several deleted files with ";58a07f8b" after their name.

[image: output of lsof | grep deleted]

This is happening to more processes like bash or ssh.

I'm using lsof version 4.87, on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)